# Why is my custom SS3.1 report returning an error "[Notice] Object of class GridState_Data could not be converted to int"

Tags: php, report, silverstripe

As an exercise to help me learn about writing custom reports, I've written a very simple custom report to list pages by their page type. I wrote the code based on the standard report cms/code/reports/BrokenLinksReport.php (included as part of the CMS) but am getting an error:

> [Notice] Object of class GridState_Data could not be converted to int

I dumped the contents of $data to ensure it was as expected, and it was. What might be causing the problem?

My code is as follows:

```
class PageListByType extends SS_Report {

    function title() {
        return "Page List by Type";
    }

    function description() {
        return "List all the pages in the site, along with their page type";
    }

    public function sourceRecords($params = array(), $sort = null, $limit = null) {
        $data = Page::get()->sort($sort);
        $returnSet = new ArrayList();
        if ($data) foreach ($data as $record) {
            $returnSet->push($record);
        }
        return $returnSet;
    }

    public function columns() {
        return array(
            array(
                'title'=>_t('PageListByTypeReport.PageName', 'Page name')
            ),
            array(
                'className'=>_t('PageListByTypeReport.ClassName', 'Page type')
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There error is the two dimensional array in the `columns` function is not being set correctly. The variable name is missing and in the incorrect place for each column.

Either you can set the columns like this:

```
public function columns() {
    return array(
        'Title' => array(
            'title'=>_t('PageListByTypeReport.PageName', 'Page name')
        ),
       'ClassName' =>  array(
            'title'=>_t('PageListByTypeReport.ClassName', 'Page type')
        )
    );
}
```

Or even simpler like this:

```
public function columns() {
    return array(
        'Title' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.PageName', 'Page name'),
        'ClassName' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.ClassName', 'Page type')
    );
}
```

The current `sourceRecords` function will work, although we can make this much simpler by just returning the results of `Page::get()` like this:

```
public function sourceRecords($params = array(), $sort = null, $limit = null) {
    $pages = Page::get()->sort($sort);
    return $pages;
}
```

Here is a working and simplified version of the Report code:

```php
class PageListByType extends SS_Report {

    function title() {
        return 'Page List by Type';
    }

    function description() {
        return 'List all the pages in the site, along with their page type';
    }

    public function sourceRecords($params = array(), $sort = null, $limit = null) {
        $pages = Page::get()->sort($sort);
        return $pages;
    }

    public function columns() {
        return array(
            'Title' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.PageName', 'Page name'),
            'ClassName' => _t('PageListByTypeReport.ClassName', 'Page type')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will be interested to know the reason. In the meantime, your code works a treat! :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I found. I hope it makes sense what the problem was.